# Converting between an ActionScript Array (Object[]) and a Vector.<Object>

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, vector, type-conversion, iteration

Are there options for converting an `Array` to a `Vector` in ActionScript without iterating the array?

What about the other way (converting a `Vector` to an `Array`)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For the `Array` to `Vector`, use the [`Vector.<TYPE>()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html#Vector%28%29) function that accept an array and will return the vector created :

```
var aObjects:Array = [{a:'1'}, {b:'2'}, {c:'3'}];
// use Vector function
var vObjects:Vector.<Object> = Vector.<Object>(aObjects);
```

For the other there is no builtin function, so you  have to do a loop over each `Vector` item and put then into an `Array`

Comment: Just a reminder, make sure to use the global "Vector.<Object>(aObjects)" function, don't use "new Vector.<Object>(aObjects)" since the new constructor doesn't work.  Took me a second to figure out why this wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
vObjects.push.apply(null, aObjects);
```

And another way to do it.

The trick here is simple. If you try to use the `concat()` method to load your array into a vector it will fail because the input is a vector and instead of adding the vector elements AS will add the whole vector as one entry. And if you were to use `push()` you'd have to go through all items in the array and add them one by one.

In ActionScript every function can be called in three ways:

- Normal way: `vObjects.push(aObjects)`

  Throws error because `aObjects` is not an `Object` but an `Array`.
- The `call` method: `vObjects.push.call(this, myObject1, myObject2, ..., myObjectN)`

  Doesn't help us because we cannot split the `aObjects` array into a comma-separated list that we can pass to the function.
- The `apply` method: `vObjects.push.apply(this, aObjects)`

  Going this route AS will happily accept the array as input and add its elements to the vector. You will still get a runtime error if the element types of the array and the vector do not match. Note the first parameter: it defines what is scoped to `this` when running the function, in most cases `null` will be fine, but if you use the `this` keyword in the function to call you should pass something other than `null`.

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.

Answer (score 0):

var myArray:Array = [].concat(myVector);

might work.

Comment: Nope, will not work because `myVector` is not an `Array` as `concat()` expects.